# How to use a pattern in an input to force it not to accept "-"?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to add a pattern in my input to not accept - between the numbers like 9-999---9 , how to do that ?

I tried to add min=0 but it accepts -9--9999----9

i just keep being able to write - in the middle of my number like 9-9--99----9

Comment: You need JavaScript for that. HTML by itself can't prevent any characters from being input. You can only stop invalid characters from being submitted.

Comment: Use a reactive form in angular and validate this field using `Validator.pattern()`

Answer (score 0):

use regex pattern:either template Driven or ReactiveForm
([^-]+) this will return invalid if user enters "-"
HTML file

```
<form [formGroup]="sumname">
    <input type="text formControlName="num">
```

invalid

in ts file using formbuilder and form group:

```
this.sumname=this.builder.group({
```

num=['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[^-]+')]]
})

Comment: I think OP only wants to forbid "-" _between_ characters. This regex will also forbid "-" signs in front, so the user can't enter negative numbers.

Comment: then we can use assertions!!@S.L.Barth

Answer (score -1):

use this .....

```js
function phonenumber(inputtxt)
{
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
  if((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
        {
      return true;
        }
      else
        {
        alert("message");
        return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please re-read the question. OP asks how to forbid "-" signs between numbers. They didn't ask for phone numbers, which sometimes _are_ spelled with "-" signs between the numbers.